# Android SDK "Android API 29 Platform" is not found on disk or corrupted | I can't fix this error but everything works

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

I am using Android Studio to program flutter apps and recently I found an error in a blue ribbon in Android Studio that said "Android SDK 'Android API 29 Platform' is missing". I tried everything to make it go away but it didn't.

Everything works in Android Studio and Flutter, Flutter doctor says there is no problems and no other errors are showing up, The apps run smoothly too.

Suddenly the error changed to 'Android SDK "Android API 29 Platform" is not found on disk or corrupter' and it still won't go away but everything still works.

[image: The error]

I've tried everything I found online...

- I moved the sdk folder to another directory
- I redownloaded the sdk folder
- I redownloaded flutter
- I re-installed Android Studio
- I cleaned the dart cache
- I cleaned the Android Studio cache
- I checked the sdk manager
- I checked the environment paths

No matter what I do, this error doesn't seem to go away

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.

1. Go to Android Studio
2. Open SDK manager
3. Select Android SDK
4. Update Android SDK location(with actual path).

> If it doesn't work. From SDK platform tab, you'll see a column for API
> label, and install your required platform.

Comment: I've already done that, The API Platform is installed and all the paths are correct and even put in the Environment paths. All the flutter apps run fine but I can't seem to be able to get rid of that error still.

Comment: Do you see this error on every project?

Comment: Yes, I've created new projects and it's still there. never goes away. no other errors happen though.

Answer (score 0):

File > Projects structure > SDK.
Select some SDK

Answer (score 0):

this has happened to me many times-the error goes away when you allow the android IDE to save your projects in the default directory-android studio projects in the C:/ drive ie C:/ Users/user/StudioProjects/myWhateverProject

If you have saved your project on a USB drive (i.e D:/ , E:/ or whatever) then the IDE cannot reference the sdk package correctly-even though the project compiles properly without any gradle build errors